# Check Mobile Number is in service using asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, .net, validation

I have one online registration form. On the registration form I have mobile no field. I used all validation to validate the mobile number.user put the false mobile number which when we call it says mobile number is not active or valid.  Mobile number doesnt actually validate if the entered mobile number is really isactive in the service or is this valid mobile number? so that we can call client and ask them for more details. Is there any way to check if the mobile number is in service or valid number in reality.Any one can help me?

Comment: Send SMS with verification code

Comment: i dont have sms gateway and client is not going to buy it :)

Comment: @Terror.Blade if they don't want to invest $0.01 for the customer, they're bad clients.

Comment: If that were possible, it would be spammers' paradise.

Comment: Do you need a solution for a specific country? There might be solutions specific for one country, but none I am aware of. (Maybe you can use WhatsApp, they have all the phone numbers ;) )